# Can I use a 3 A fuse to a 13 A wire?

Tags: mains, cables, fuses

I made an extension cable from a 3 A cable because I wanted a thinner cable.

The plug came with a 5 A, 240 V fuse but I replaced the fuse with a 3 A, 240 V fuse.

If the appliances I use take more than 3 A I expect the fuse to blow and everything to be fine. What are the risks in this approach? Is there anything to worry about?

Links:

- https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/wilko-5-amp-white-3-pin-plug-with-fuse/p/0015262
- https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/wilko-2-way-extension-lead/p/5357240
- https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/wilko-4-pack-3-amp-fuses/p/5349240

I can't find the cable but it was rated above 3 A.

Cable spec: 3 core 0.5mm cable PVC "ready to use with 3 amps or 720 watts at 240 volts" "suitable for light fittings, electric lamps and electrical appliances up ot 720 watts"

Comment: A link to the cable type and fuse seems like a good idea. You should also state what voltage the cable carries.

Comment: @Andyaka I can't seem to find that but let's assume it's 240V- I think it is and will confirm before turning the power on. What determines the voltage a cable carriers- is it the amount of insulation?

Comment: Worry about heat, inefficiency

Comment: There's nothing I can help you with without data sheets and definitive details. The devil hides in the details.

Comment: Good shout @jsotola. For anyone seeing this questions, don't close please. Tomorrow I'll add the cable's spec!

Comment: @Andyaka I went and looked, and added all the details from the label (edited into last line of the question)

Comment: Where does the 13 A number come from?

Comment: @Hearth The cable is attached to a a plug, and the plug is plugged into a mains socket

Comment: @Lucien That doesn't exactly answer my question.

Comment: @Hearth I don't know enough about electronics to answer your question then. I know that the mains can provide 13A, so my worry is that 13A could surge through the wire and cause harm somehow.

Comment: @Lucien The mains can provide a lot more than 13 A. I assume you mean there's a 13 A breaker on the circuit? That would be uncommon where I am (15 A or 20 A breakers are the norm here) but other countries probably have different regulations.

Comment: (Fuses in plugs are great - and quite possibly Britain.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming when you say "3.5A cable" you mean a type approved 0.5mm2 flex, then there is no issue with protecting this with a 3A fuse in the plug.  You must, however, ensure that the maximum load being served has a normal current draw of less than 3A.

The current/time graphs for BS1362 fuses (those in UK mains plugs) can be found here [BS1362 fuse operation characteristics](https://www.pat-testing-training.net/articles/fuse-operation-characteristics.php), and this highlights that such fuses must be capable of carrying a 60% overload for at least 30min.  Even at 6A (a 100% overload), it may take 10min for a 3A fuse to blow.

Therefore you should *not* depend on fuses to provide protection to low (<60%) overloads, and instead that should be done by design.

However, at normal room temperature, 0.5mm2 cable is explicitly speced as being safe to be protected by a 3A BS1362 fuse.  If it is being used in a higher temperature environment (say a boiler cupboard) or covered in insulation, then either a high temperature cable, or a heavier gauge may be needed.

Comment: What would happen if I plugged in appliances that took 4A? Or 13A? Would the fuse blow safely or should I not rely on this?

Is it safe to rely on the manufacturer's guide (Amp/Volt ratings)?

Comment: @Lucien Fuse could blow (not "will" but "could" if it's only 4A. Probably will if it's 13A.). Whether a fuse blowing is considered safe, or whether it should be considered more of a last resort type of thing, I don't really know. I've never *heard* of a fuse blowing being dangerous, in normal circumstances (some really big short circuits can make fuses explode). The danger is usually the wire. The wire will be fine of course since it's designed for 13A.

Comment: The wire is designed for more than 3A but less than 5A. I have requested an info sheet and will publish it here and reply here before turning on the power.

Comment: Added more info (last line of question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, please mark as answered